# Data model in Cassandra and proper deletion Strategy

Tags: cassandra

I have following table in cassandra:

```
CREATE TABLE article ( 
id text, 
price int, 
validFrom timestamp,     
PRIMARY KEY (id, validFrom)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (validFrom DESC);
```

With articles and historical price information (validFrom is a timestamp of new price). Article price changes often. I want to query for

1. Historic price for a particular article.
2. Last price for an article.

From my understanding, I can solve both problems with following query:
`select id, price from article where id = X validFrom < Y limit 1;`
This query uses article id as restriction, query uses the partition key. Since the clustering order is based on the validFrom timestamp in reversed order, cassandra can efficient perform this query.
Am I getting this right?

What is the best approach to delete old data (house-keeping). Let's assume, I want delete **all** articles with `validFrom > 20150101 and validFrom < 20151231`. Since I don't have a primary key, this would be inefficient, even if I use an index on validFrom, right? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use external tools for that:

- Spark with [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) (even in the local mode).  Code could look as following (note that I'm using `validfrom` as name, not `validFrom`, as it's not escaped in your schema):

```scala
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
val data = sc.cassandraTable("test", "article")
   .where("validfrom >= '2020-07-28T11:50:00Z' AND validfrom < '2020-07-28T12:50:00Z'")
   .select("id", "validfrom")
data.deleteFromCassandra("test", "article", keyColumns=SomeColumns("id", "validfrom"))
```

- use [DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html) to do find the matching entries and output them into the file (`output.csv` in my case), and then perform their deletion:

```sh
bin/dsbulk unload -url output.csv \
  -query "SELECT id, validfrom FROM test.article WHERE token(id) > :start AND token(id) <= :end AND validFrom >= '2020-07-28T11:50:00Z' AND validFrom < '2020-07-28T12:50:00Z' ALLOW FILTERING"
bin/dsbulk load -query "DELETE from test.article WHERE id = :id and validfrom = :validfrom" \
  -url output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Alex Ott's answer, this comment of yours is incorrect:

> This query uses article id as restriction, query uses the partition key. Since the clustering order is based on price, cassandra can efficient perform this query.

The rows are *not* ordered by `price`. They are ordered by `validFrom` in reverse-chronological order. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, you're right. The table is ordered by validFrom timestamp. I changed the description in my Post