# Is it possible to delete data older than 'x' in Cassandra using only timestamp PK field and w/o ALLOW FILTERING and TTL option?

Tags: cassandra

Title says all. I have a table *timestampTEST*

```
create table timestampTEST ( timestamp timestamp, test text, PRIMARY KEY(timestamp));
```

When trying to

```
select * from messagesbytimestampTEST where timestamp > '2021-01-03' and timestamp < '2021-01-04' ;
```

I got error

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING"
```

What I saw here https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/refTimeUuidFunctions.html it this sample (but I assume it is just *part* of the cql query):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
   WHERE t > maxTimeuuid('2013-01-01 00:05+0000')
   AND t < minTimeuuid('2013-02-02 10:00+0000')
```

I know above is related to *timeuuid*, but I have tried it also and it yields same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do in CQL without `ALLOW FILTERING`.  The primary reason is that in your table, primary key is the same as partition key, and to fulfill your query you need to scan data on all servers.  This happens because the partition key is not ordered - the value is hashed, and used to select the server on which it will be stored.  So CurrentTime-1sec will be on one server, CurrentTime-10sec - on another, etc.

Usually, for such queries people are using some external tools, like, DSBulk, or Spark with Spark Cassandra Connector. You can refer to following answers that I already provided on that topic:

- [Data model in Cassandra and proper deletion Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63121594/data-model-in-cassandra-and-proper-deletion-strategy/63128795#63128795)
- [Delete records in Cassandra table based on time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59859771/delete-records-in-cassandra-table-based-on-time-range/59861178#59861178)